# Deploying apps with multiple ruby versions using Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

Is this still the current state of deploying apps using different rubies with Passenger ? – http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/ #rails @ phusion_nl .

If it is, then its a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the cleanest way to have independent instances of rails applications, read this tutorial to have some overview http://niczsoft.com/2011/03/passenger-standalone-with-god-on-rvm/